# React-fetch requires react-addons, but there is no react/addons folder

Tags: reactjs, webpack, fetch

**Edit:** The author has patched it.

I'm beginning to use `react-fetch` (well, trying to), and when trying to run `webpack`, I got this error :

```
ERROR in ./~/react-fetch/build/react-fetch.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' E:\Users\Adrien\Documents\GitHub\brigad-admin-frontend/node_modules/react/addons in E:\Users\Adrien\Documents\GitHub\brigad-admin-frontend\node_modules\react-fetch\build
 @ ./~/react-fetch/build/react-fetch.js 17:19-42
```

But, as the error says, I have no `react/addons` folder (I'm using `React 15.0.1`).

Does anybody have had this issue before?

Thanks in advance.

PS: Here's my webpack.config.js:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

const nodeDir = `${__dirname}/node_modules`;

const config = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      react: `${nodeDir}/react`,
      'react-dom': `${nodeDir}/react-dom`,
      'react-router': `${nodeDir}/react-router`,
      'react-fetch': `${nodeDir}/react-fetch`,
      'react-bootstrap': `${nodeDir}/react-bootstrap`,
      velocity: `${nodeDir}/velocity-animate`,
      moment: `${nodeDir}/moment`,
      slimscroll: `${nodeDir}/slimscroll`,
    },
  },
  entry: {
    routes: [
      'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
      'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
      './public/src/routes/js/main',
    ],
    vendors: [
      'react', 'react-dom', 'react-router', 'react-fetch', 'react-bootstrap',
      'velocity', 'moment', 'slimscroll',
    ],
    // chartVendors: ['raphael', 'morris'],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public/dist'),
    // publicPath: path.join(__dirname, 'public/dist/'),
    filename: 'bundles/[name].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: 'chunks/[name].chunk.js',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        loader: 'react-hot',
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
        loader: 'babel',
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        loader: 'style!css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1' +
        '&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendors', './bundles/vendors.js', Infinity),
  ],
};

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 1):

React API has changed. `import React from 'react/addons'` isn't valid in the current version. I can see the author uses `React.addons.cloneWithProps` from there.

[The documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.cloneelement) suggests using `React.cloneElement` instead.

You could tweak the code accordingly and submit a PR to get this fixed.

Comment: Well, turns out I'm not experimented enough to tweak the code, I'll just open an issue.

Comment: I have the idea implemented [here](https://gist.github.com/bebraw/77c8168e54a4ce3257f9). Maybe you could adapt the code based on that and PR.

Comment: Nice work, I'm trying to fix it but when building I get `Failed at the react-fetch@0.0.7 build script 'gulp clean && NODE_ENV=production gulp build'.`
I've never used gulp before, and am pretty new to React too.

Comment: That line could fail if you are on Windows. `&& NODE_ENV=production` works only on Unix.

Comment: One option would be to use the component I linked to. You can link the react-fetch guy to that so he fix his. :+1:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110354/discussion-between-zephir77167-and-bebraw).

Comment: I made react-fetch a while ago. I will update it and reply to your issue on github. By the way, you don't need to alias those modules, you can already import them via their name.